# Capybara Poltergeist doesn't toggle dropdowns after click

Tags: javascript, cucumber, capybara, poltergeist, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap website and for some reason the dropdowns stopped working.

My dropdown

```
<li class="dropdown nav-item">
    <a id="toggle-link">Click to reveal </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <a id="inside-dropdown" href="/profile/edit">Mon compte</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Capybara does

```
find('a#toggle-link').click
```

But nothing happens on Poltergeist, the dropdown menu isn't beng revealed anymore (fine with selenium on safari). When looking at the html screenshot, it would seem the javascript failed to add the "open" class" on the dropdown

I am unsure what changed from before, apart from a gem update that boosted several gems. Poltergeist was untouched, Capybara bumped from 2.7.1 (but I tried rolling back, didn't change anything)

Anyone experienced such problems ?

Capybara 2.10.1
Poltergeist 1.10.0
Cucumber 2.4.0
Rails5

EDIT : after my gem upgrades, notable changes

- Capybara 2.7.1 -> 2.10.1
- Bootstrap 4.0.0.alpha3.1 -> 4.0.0alpha4
- 5.0.0.rc1 -> 5.0.0.1

Comment: It might be a race condition to add the event listener. Try to add a sleep before clicking the link to see if it's the case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but adding some sleep didn't change.
I don't believe there could be a race condition since the whole DOM is loaded before Capybara executes (and Capybara was designed to avoid common sync issues like that afaik).

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris  There can be race conditions, especially if JS resources are being loaded by other JS on an as needed basis.  What version of phantomjs are you running and did you happen to update bootstrap or anything else that would change the click handlers?

Comment: I've the same issue with bootstrap 3. Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We experienced the same kind of problems. In our case, `phantomjs` was unable to parse js sources due to an unsupported ES6 keyword. But it does not raise an exception and just silently fails. The entire js stack wasn't loaded, including the code which handle clicks on dropdowns.

Comment: You may find here a related issue https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/823

Comment: Hey yes that's actually the problem I had back then ! Forgot to post the answer...